# Overridden properties issue in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, overriding, llvm

I have a subclass of `UIButton` as follows:

```
class VectorizedButton: UIButton {

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works great, until I added this line in my root controller:

```
var twitterButton: TwitterButton?
```

`TwitterButton` extends `VectorizedButton`.

Here is the error I get:

> ...UIView+Vectorized.swift:42:7: Class 'VectorizedButton' has no initializers
>   ...UIView+Vectorized.swift:44:18: Stored property 'highlighted' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers

Easy, let's set a default value:

```
override var highlighted: Bool = false
```

Tougher error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: super.init called multiple times in initializer
<unknown>:0: error: super.init called multiple times in initializer
<unknown>:0: error: super.init called multiple times in initializer
```

Try overriding init?

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    highlighted = false
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Even more errors:

```
error: 'self' used before super.init call
    highlighted = false
                ^
error: 'self' used before super.init call
    highlighted = false
    ^
```

Anyone cares to explain what's going on here?

Comment: is everything in the same project, or have you got sub-projects/frameworks?... and do you have the latest Xcode 6A1052d

Comment: @bandejapaisa Same project, latest Xcode. FWIW, `TwitterButton` and `VectorizedButton` are in the same swift file called `UIView+Vectorized.swift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had to add the required init

Here is what I did :

```
class VectorizedButton: UIButton {

  override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

}

class TwitterButton: VectorizedButton {

}
```

And in a ViewController :

```
var twitterButton: TwitterButton?
```

Works fine like this.

You wanted to override the highlighted property and create the twitterButton as Optional, so you need to implement an init in your class.

You cannot set the highlighted property with this :

```
override var highlighted: Bool = false
```

You need to set it in the init, or like this :

```
override var highlighted: Bool {

    get { return false }
    set { super.highlighted = newValue }
}
```

And for this :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  highlighted = false
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

You need to set your property after the call to super.init.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I guess I assumed the swift compiler will have a consistent error when I needed a required initializer.